# How to put fontello icon in input value?

Tags: html, fontello

Say I have this code:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send" />
```

But after the text "Send" I want to have a [fontello](http://fontello.com/) icon. Obviously this doesn't work:

```
<input type="submit" value="Send <i class='icon-right-circle'></i>" />
```

In my fontello *demo.html* file, the code for that icon is `0xe81c`. Isn't there a away to put this icon in the input value? Like as an HTML entity or something?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This should work:

`<input type="submit" value="Send &#xf001;" style="font-family:icons" />`

There are two steps:

1. use `&#xf001;` to output character. You can find code in fontello css file, someting like `content:'\f001'`, just do the replace `\f001` -> `&#xf001;`.
2. set font-family for this element. I use `icons` in my code, you should check the font name in css file.

---

Further step:
You can customize your own class:
`.myfont {
  font-family:icons;
}`

and the html will be:
`<input type="submit" value="Send &#xf001;" class="myfont" />`

Comment: This answer is very cool, I didn't know you could do this. Usually I just use absolute positioning.

Comment: By default, the font-family for fontello is set as "font-family: fontello".

Comment: @RobKohr by default, the font-family is set as "font-family: fontello" only when you use the class,  not for all fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in CSS:

```
input[type='submit'] {
    background-image: url(images/icon.gif);
    background-position: 7px 7px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Other Option is use `button type="submit"` instead of `input`

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">
    <i class='icon-right-circle'></i> Text
</button>
```

Comment: That defeats the whole purpose of fontello.

Comment: This still doesn't answer my question. I'm aware of other methods of making the button work (your method, as well as making a simple anchor link and making it submit the form via JS). I'm asking if there is a way to put the icon in the value of an input.